# AngularJS directive for watching height change

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive that allows you to bind a CSS property to the height of another

```
m.directive('bindToHeight', function ($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var attributes = scope.$eval(attrs['bindToHeight']);
            var targetElem = angular.element(document.querySelector(attributes[1]));

            // Watch for changes
            scope.$watch(
                function () {
                    return targetElem.height();
                },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue != oldValue) {
                        elem.css(attributes[0], newValue);
                    }
                });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<div bind-to-height="['bottom','#theContainer']">
```

Now what I have noticed is that it only works once the contents of  `#theContainer` is updated twice.  The first time it seems to send a height of 0, the second time it gets the height properly.

This div is updated from another angular controller and the height can change depending on what content is in there.  The reason I wrote this was because something is stacked (position absolute) above it and needs to adjust its height to match.

When I first run the page I get the following values

- OldValue: 287, NewValue: 287
- OldValue: 287, NewValue: 0

Have I written the directive wrong or is there some better way to do this?

Comment: How about an `attr.$observe()`,  I think that will be later in the digest cycle because it "Observes an interpolated attribute"

Comment: @Dylan how would I use that in my example? Cant seem to find information on how to use it in this case. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try deepwatching your element:

```
m.directive('bindToHeight', function ($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var attributes = scope.$eval(attrs['bindToHeight']);
            var targetElem = angular.element(document.querySelector(attributes[1]));

            // Watch for changes
            scope.$watch(
                function () {
                    return targetElem.height();
                },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue != oldValue) {
                        elem.css(attributes[0], newValue);
                    }
                }, true);//ADD A BOOLEAN TO DEEPWATCH ALL THE PROPERTIES OF THE OBJECT
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This isn't going to matter since you are watching the return value of a function, which is just a primitive Number.

Comment: What @JohnBledsoe said! But I did actually try this before hand in an act of desperation :)